# How to dynamically set the bundle from AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel, viewmodel-savedstate

My **ViewModelFactory**:

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val viewModelMap: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, ViewModelAssistedFactory<out ViewModel>>,
    owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    defaultArgs: Bundle?
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {

    @Throws(IllegalStateException::class)
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, handle: SavedStateHandle): T {
        return viewModelMap[modelClass]?.create(handle) as? T ?: throw IllegalStateException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

**Activity**:

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
protected val viewModel: ViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(getViewModelClass()) }
```

**ViewModel**:

```
@AssistedInject.Factory
interface Factory : ViewModelAssistedFactory<SplashViewModel>
```

And I was wondering how can I provide the defaultArgs dynamically instead of:

**ActivityModule**

```
@Module
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Nullable
        @Provides
        fun provideDefaultArgs(): Bundle? {
            return null
        }
    }
```

The idea is to have the possibility to send a parameter to the ViewModel, let's say an ID for a DetailActivity.
Normally I use an "init" method, but If I could use the `StateHandle map` would be even better. Something like [this](https://github.com/ivanalvarado/architecture-components/blob/master/mvvm/app/src/main/java/com/ivanalvarado/architecture_components/viewmodel/UserDetailViewModel.kt#L32) and [this](https://github.com/ivanalvarado/architecture-components/blob/ec50763d775334eef47eb4b2216c78c4d9fa17ae/mvvm/app/src/main/java/com/ivanalvarado/architecture_components/ui/UserDetailActivity.kt#L19).

Makes sense? Is it possible?

Comment: This might sound crazy, but it sounds like you need to provide `ViewModelProvider.Factory` via AssistedInject.

Comment: Shouldn't we try to `AssistedInject` the `Bundle` like we do with the `ViewModelAssistedFactory`?

Comment: Exactly. To get an instance of `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory` with the `Bundle` passed in through `AssistedInject`, you will end up creating the VMFactory through assisted injection.

Comment: can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60669372/retain-edittext-with-screen-rotation-using-databinding-library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across 2 solutions:

**Solution A:**

Change our ViewModelFactory to:

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val viewModelMap: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, ViewModelAssistedFactory<out ViewModel>>
) {
    fun create(owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner, defaultArgs: Bundle? = null): AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory {
        return object : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, handle: SavedStateHandle): T {
                return viewModelMap[modelClass]?.create(handle) as? T ?: throw IllegalStateException("Unknown ViewModel class")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
protected val viewModel: ViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory.create(this, args).get(getViewModelClass()) }
```

Also, we can simplify our ActivityModule to (example):

```
@AssistedModule
@Module(includes = [AssistedInject_SplashActivityModule::class])
abstract class SplashActivityModule{

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SplashViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindFactory(factory: SplashViewModel.Factory): ViewModelAssistedFactory<out ViewModel>
}
```

This [post](https://proandroiddev.com/connecting-the-dots-44d8fa79f14) by **Tomáš Mlynarič** helped with this solution.

**Solution B:**

Create a `Factory` without injected dependencies:

```
class ViewModelFactoryAlt<out V : ViewModel>(
    private val viewModelFactory: ViewModelAssistedFactory<V>,
    owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    defaultArgs: Bundle? = null
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, handle: SavedStateHandle): T {
        return viewModelFactory.create(handle) as T
    }
}
```

Create our `ViewModelAssitedFactory` like:

```
class HelloWorldViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val dependencyA: DependencyA,
    ...
) : ViewModelAssistedFactory<HelloWorldViewModel> {
    override fun create(stateHandle: SavedStateHandle): HelloWorldViewModel {
        return HelloWorldViewModel(stateHandle, dependencyA, ...)
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
@Inject
lateinit var factory: HelloWorldViewModelFactory
private val viewModel: HelloWorldViewModel by viewModels { ViewModelFactoryAlt(factory, this, intent.extras) }
```

This [post](https://proandroiddev.com/injecting-viewmodel-from-hard-to-easy-c06c0fe1c8e9) by **Elye** helped with this solution.